# Why does my chat room report more feeds than are actually there?

Tags: support, chat, feed

According to the [feeds page for V'dibarta Bam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468/vdibarta-bam?tab=feeds) we have five feeds.

Or four.  It depends on what part of the page you believe:

[image: screen shot]

I wondered if the extra were an inactive or deleted feed, but I don't see any hints of this on the page, like say a "history" or "deactivated" or "busted" link.  I'm a moderator on that site, so even if there were a reason to keep that from regular users, I would think that if it existed I'd be able to see that.

Do we have a stealth feed, or is the total wrong?

Comment: Hmm, adding a new feed and then removing it updates the count to 6 and 5 respectively. So it's not some weird caching thing. It must be a phantom!

Comment: We used to have another one way-back-when which was only active for about 49 days a year, but I thought we got rid of it. I wonder if its the culprit somehow.

Comment: @DoubleAA oh, I forgot all about that one!  I find no evidence of it there now, but I wonder if it's lurking behind the scenes anyway.  (If so, I wonder what the difference is between that and #2 here (parshablog), which had gone dormant and needed to have its URL updated.)

Comment: The room has an insatiable hunger.